# Translate circular references in Excel to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

So if I have let's say the following Excel formulas where A to I represent the columns.

```
A  B  C  D  E  F  G                     H                                       
1  2  3  4  5  6  =IF(A=1;"Yes";"No")   =IF(G = "Yes"; "Absolutely Yes"; "No")

I
=IF(H = "Absolutely Yes"; "Definitely Yes!"; "No")
```

Right now I am translating this with multiple #temp tables in SQL Server. So

```
SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G, 
       IIF(A=1, 'Yes','No') AS CONCLUSION_1
INTO #TEMP_1
FROM TABLE

SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G, CONCLUSION_1, 
       IIF(CONCLUSION_1 = 'Yes', 'Absolutely Yes', 'No') AS CONCLUSION_2
INTO #TEMP_2
FROM #TEMP_1

SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G, CONCLUSION_1, 
       IIF(CONCLUSION_2 = 'Absolutely Yes', 'Definitely Yes', 'No') AS FINAL_CONCLUSION
INTO FINAL_TABLE
FROM #TEMP_2
```

This is just a simple example, but the Excel formulas contain nested IF statements which I translate with IIF or CASE statements, the outcomes of which need to be reused, and then AGAIN those second time outcomes need to be reused just like in the small example. However, there must be a better way than creating #temp tables?

Comment: Those aren't circular references.  If A=1, set Conclusion_1 to yes, and the other two to "Definitely Yes" .. I assume it's not that easy so maybe you missed something?

Answer (score 2):

Why not do them all at the same time? They're not recursive or circular in any way:

```
SELECT A,B,C,D,E,F,G, 
       IIF(A=1, 'Yes','No') AS CONCLUSION_1,
       IIF(A=1, 'Absolutely Yes', 'No') AS CONCLUSION_2,
       IIF(A=1, 'Definitely Yes', 'No') AS FINAL_CONCLUSION
FROM TABLE
```

Comment: It was just to demonstrate an example. I understand that it can be solved like that, but the formulas are really complex and rely on each other to be solved..

Comment: Then please edit your example so that it represents the problem you're trying to solve.  Kudos for putting together a simple example but it mustn't be so simple as to not actually exhibit the problem!

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought I would be clearer with a simple example. But I have used the #temp function for now, and thanks for your help I really appreciate it! :)